# How i can sniff ethernet with source and destionation mac address

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am tring to snif ethernet packet, but i cant get mac adress from raw package, starting with IP Header
i add picture of wireshark output and script output.i dont use struct for that reason but `dest_mac = data[:6]` manupulation is also give same result. (windows on physical device and virtualbox as NIC)

```
import socket
import sys

def receiveData(s):
    data = ''
    try:
        data = s.recvfrom(65000)
    except:
        print('Data read error')
        sys.exc_info()
    return data[0]


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(('192.168.56.1', 0))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

data = receiveData(s)
dest_mac = data[:6]

j = 0
for i in data:
    print(str(hex(j)) + ' ' + hex(i))
    j += 1
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

virtual interface has no traffic just i sent ping 192.168.56.2 to 192.168.56.1
can be echo or reply this one more close.
But when i check total lenght in wireshark 0x49, when i check my code output 0x3b  0x49-0x3b this difference is my lost bytes 'cos i can see 0x45 it is 0x0e index number in wireshark.

Wireshark
[image: Wireshark and script output]

Output (just move to excel for easy read)
[image: Wireshark and script output]

Comment: Have you ever heard about `scapy` package?

Comment: Can you show the complete Wireshark analysis of the packet, without the console window covering it? The bytes in your output don't even come close to matching the bytes shown in the Wireshark output.  Are you sure Wireshark is displaying the same packet that your program is receiving?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i edditted the output, could you check and please share your idea.

Comment: @SamEbison thanks for your answer also i test scapy with your sugestion it is so powerfull library. I hadnt heard before. Now i am tring to solve with socket library.

Comment: @doni_darko Glad to hear. Good luck!